# How can i implement the offset x function in a slideshow with javascript

Tags: javascript, position, offset

I have a slider that starts at click o button and i wants every image to be loaded at a offset of 200 px in comparison with the previous one.Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var image1=new Image()
image1.src="img0.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="img1.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="img2.jpg"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="img3.jpg"
var image5=new Image()
image5.src="img4.jpg"

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var step=1
function slideit(){
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
    if(step<5)
        step++

    else
        step=1
    setTimeout("slideit()",500)

}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="slideit()">Try it</button>
<img src="img0.jpg" name="slide" width="100" height="100" position = "absolute">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like this to be done in pure JavaScript and not jQuery.

Comment: I'd recommend using an array to store your images, and get rid of that `eval()` completely. Then, you can multiply the offset amount by your step to get the offset you want.

Comment: can you post an example ?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be nice :) btw, is there a reason why you don't use a array ?

Comment: not a good idea to make slider without jQuery - you'll spend hellotof the time debugging and making it work in all browsers

Comment: i will post in a few min an array solution, at least i will try

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using offsetx and offsettop in JavaScript or position x and positon y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605791/using-offsetx-and-offsettop-in-javascript-or-position-x-and-positon-y)